# Synchronizing domains

Tags: arcgis-desktop, domains

I am using a non-ESRI outside source to synchronize to some domains in the ESRI arcmap.  Would I need to synchronize to matching coded values stored in the armap fields or can i synchronize to and using the descriptions of those coded values?